# Is it safe to store username in a cookie?

Tags: php, cookies

I noticed a lot of session/cookie setups only store the token value.  I also store the username so that it checks the DB for both the username and session value just as a small added security.  But I wonder if that is a security risk since if a hacker hijacks their token code they will know which user is belongs to?  I have the token expire every two minutes.  Thanks.

Comment: You can answer this yourself: Could I do anything malicious on your site if I changed my username cookie to 'Mr J'?

Comment: I think it depends on the site.. me my self, I think that even a username can be to sensitive.

Comment: why checking both username and session id would be more secure than just session id? if it is actually more secure maybe you could store a hashed version of the username in cookies

Comment: @MikeB Hm... do cookies accept spaces? lol (just kidding) but you are (technically) right though, and technically speaking, that would need to be `Mr_J` right? ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why would spaces in cookie values cause a problem?

Comment: @MikeB "That", I can't say for certain. Can a cookie value have spaces? (curious)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Apologies, `<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {var_dump($_COOKIE['username']);} setcookie('username', 'my long test value');`

Comment: @MikeB Not a problem; I did figure out the missing characters, but thank you for the edit. Now I see that cookies can accept spaces and I never knew that till now. So as you said and I did agree with you with your initial comment which I `+1` by the way ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Usernames are generally safe to be stored as a cookie as long as they are not the only data checked when accessing sensitive areas.

Its better practice to store all data in cookies hashed, this will be more secure and safe enough for most applications.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem to keep username in cookie, but the problem is how you are making use of this username cookie. If it's being use in authentication than it creates the problem. You have to make sure that, cookies can be change by novice user as well.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention why.  I just want to the user to see his username on certain pages without me having to use a query to pull it from the DB.

Comment: if that's the only case than there are no such a securities issue in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a column of usernames and an another column of the their hash. Then it'll more secure for you. If you don't want to store the usernames directly then you can store their hashes in the browser.